# Filtering pandas DataFrame by values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

There is a pandas dataframe:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c','d'],'c2':[1,2,3,4]})

c1  c2
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   d   4
```

And a pandas Series:

```
list1 = pd.Series(['b','c','e','f'])

Out[6]:
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    e
```

How to create a new data frame that contains rows where c1 is in list1.

output:

```
c1  c2
0   b   2
1   c   3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `df.isin`:

```
In [582]: df[df.c1.isin(list1)]
Out[582]: 
  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

Or, using `df.loc`, if you want to modify your slice:

```
In [584]: df.loc[df.c1.isin(list1), :]
Out[584]: 
  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `query`

```
In [1133]: df.query('c1 in @list1')
Out[1133]:
  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

Or, using `isin`

```
In [1134]: df[df.c1.isin(list1)]
Out[1134]:
  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

Answer (score 2):

Both @JohnGalt's and @COLDSPEED's answers are more idiomatic `pandas`.  Please don't use these answers.  They are intended to be fun and illustrative of other parts of the `pandas` and `numpy` api.

**Alt 1**
This is utilizing `numpy.in1d` which acts as a proxy for `pd.Series.isin`

```
df[np.in1d(df.c1.values, list1.values)]

  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

---

**Alt 2**
Use `set` logic

```
df[df.c1.apply(set) & set(list1)]

  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

---

**Alt 3**
Use `pd.Series.str.match`

```
df[df.c1.str.match('|'.join(list1))]

  c1  c2
1  b   2
2  c   3
```

Comment: now it's getting really challenging to find yet another way to do that... ;)

Comment: Better +1 before that pandas guy comes and trashes you for using numpy :^)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ we're good (-: I do right by everyone by calling it out.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sake of completenes**

yet another way (definitely not the best one) to achieve that:

```
In [4]: df.merge(list1.to_frame(name='c1'))
Out[4]:
  c1  c2
0  b   2
1  c   3
```